# html body scrollbar position

Tags: html, menu, scrollbar

I am working on a page with a menu bar.
the height of the menu bar is 40px
and I set the top of the body tag to 40px too.
However, the scrollbar of the body tag is still at top=0px.

Comment: can you share your code..

Comment: please share your code, then only we can understand

Answer (score 1):

To do this approach you can use `flex` display. you should wrap your main content in another section and scroll the wrapper inside itself.

here an example :

```
<body>
   <nav class="nav">
      <!-- *********** your nav items ******************* -->
   </nav>
   <main class="content">
      <!-- your content should be placed here ****************-->
   </main>
</body>
```

and the CSS code :

```
body {
   display: flex;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
   flex-direction: column;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.nav {
   height: 40px;
  background: red;
}
.content {
   flex: 1;
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
  background: blue;
}
```